# Обработчик событий в Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, click, onclicklistener

Есть канвас с имитацией падающих блоков (реализовано координатами с отрисовкой через .fillRect(), с дальнейшим изменением Y ). Хочу повесить обработчик на клик по блоку, скажем чтобы блок исчезал. Как мне это реализовать? Или сама идея взаимодействия с рисующимся объектом неверна?

```
function drawSquare() {
  //очистка поля
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ROW_COUNT * SIZE, COLUMN_COUNT * SIZE);
  //отрисовка квадратика на сгенерированной позиции
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillRect(x * SIZE, y * SIZE, SIZE, SIZE);


  document.getElementById("catch").innerText = `CATCH: ${countCatch}`; 
  document.getElementById("lost").innerText = `LOST: ${countLost}`; 
}

//анимация падения
function offsetY() {
  //обнуление позиции
  if (y === COLUMN_COUNT) {
    HIT.play();
    generatePosition();
    //увеличение счетчика пропущенных
    countLost++;
  } else {
    y++;
  }
  drawSquare();
}
```

Comment: Для canvas придется повесить обработчик события на сам холст, а уже по координатам перебирать блоки и проверять нет ли совпадений. Есть еще способ с получением цвета пикселя в месте клика. Если цвет совпадает с цветом блоков, то можно определить клик на них. Еще можно каждому блоку задавать уникальный цвет и по полученным данным определять по какому блоку был клик. В вашем случае можно по координатам X оставлять для проверки только соответствующую группу блоков.

Comment: Если все блоки должны быть одного цвета, то можно создать параллельный холст с падающими блоками с уникальными цветами и брать данные оттуда. А можно все переделать на SVG, для нового кадра менять атрибут `y` элементов `rect` и на эти элементы повесить слушателей событий как на обычные элементы DOM. Или слушать событие на всем SVG, а уже с помощью `event.target` определять ваш блок.